# Why is OpenCV performing poorly on Raspberry Pi 3B+?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

Running on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (Arm processor)

OpenCV C++ 3.4 static libs built libs from source with relevant flags `-DENABLE_NEON=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWITH_V4L=ON`

Using a basic ELP USB webcam (not using raspi camera because I eventually want multiple cameras)

This basic program to capture and render frames is getting something like 2 or 3 FPS.. That just can't be right!

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/shape.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <thread>

#include "time.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  VideoCapture cap(0);
  cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
  cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
  cap.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);
  cap.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'));

  long startMs = timeMs();
  int count = 0;
  for(;;) {
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    imshow("Camera", frame);

    if (++count == 30) {
      long elapsedMs = (timeMs() - startMs);
      double fps = count * 1000.0 / elapsedMs;
      cout << "FPS: " << fps << endl;
      startMs = timeMs();
      count = 0;
    }

    waitKey(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As so often seems to happen, the answer becomes apparent right after caving and posting the question..

The issue was that my v4l2-ctl configuration for the camera had been set earlier in some tinkering and was still active with a very high `exposure_absolute` setting which was limiting the framerate